# Does converse of Lagrange's theorem hold in $A_{4} \times \Bbb Z_{2}?$

Tags: group-theory

Does converse of Lagrange's theorem hold in $A_{4} \times \Bbb Z_{2}?$

The order of this group is $24$ and I'm unable to find a subgroup of order 4.Does there exist any group of order $4$ in this group$?$

Moreover, Is there any quick way to know the orders of subgroups of a particular group$?$

Comment: Can’t you construct a subgroup of order $4$ with an element of order $2$ in $A_4$ (e.g., (12)(34)) and the element of order $2$ in $Z_2$?

Comment: @Shaun:  isn’t $(12)$ in $S_4$ but not $A_4$?

Comment: @J.W. Tanner, if I construct a group generated by $3$ elements of $A_{4}$ and $1$ of $Z_{2}$ then it is of order $4$. Is there any quick way to solve such questions, or I must write all elements and then construct subgroups of all orders$?$

Comment: Let $a$ be the generator of $\Bbb Z_2$. Then $$\lvert \langle (12)(34)\rangle\times \langle a\rangle\rvert=4.$$

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that error, @J.W.Tanner.

Comment: That’s ok, @Shaun; your answer may be a valid alternative to the currently accepted one

Comment: Well, if you say so, @J.W.Tanner; I think it doesn't answer all the OP's questions. I've posted is as an answer anyway. Thank you.

Comment: By Sylow's Theorem if $p$ is a prime, $a \ge 0$ and $p^a$ divides the order of a finite group $G$, then $G$ has a subgroup of order $p^a$. So you don't need to worry about prime powers. You just need to think abbout subgroups of orders $6$ and $12$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $A_4$ is the alternating group of $4$ elements, it contains an subgroup of order $4$. In fact, this subgroup is normal, and the only (proper) normal subgroup of $A_4$. (Hint: think $(2,2)$-cycles.) This subgroup is isomorphic to the Klein-4 group.

By taking the product of this group with the trivial subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/2$, it follows that the product still has order $4$ and is a subgroup of $A_4 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$.

Comment: Did you mean the trivial *sub*group of $\Bbb Z/2$?

Comment: Oops, thanks for the typo correction!

Answer (score 0):

Let $a$ be the generator of $\Bbb Z_2$. Then

$$\lvert \langle (12)(34)\rangle\times \langle a\rangle\rvert=4.
$$